# any alternatives to Amazon Windows Virtual Machine hosting?

Tags: windows, azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

Does anyone know if there are any competing hosting alternatives I can explore other than Amazon Web Services for running very small instances of Windows virtual machines? I have used AWS for years but am thinking that it might be worth-while to see if there are better alternatives.

In particular, the scenario I have is this: I have created a Windows virtual machine image with the applications and configuration I want and then spin up VMs based on that image as I need from on the AWS spot market. I can go weeks at a time without needing any virtual machines but then will spin up 20 VMs for a few hours to do a particular job. I typically pay around .61 cents an hour per micro Windows VM running on AWS (keep in mind that the AWS spot market is way cheaper than reserved instances).

Does Microsoft Azure or any other service support a similar scenario? I don't mind paying a little more if the performance and such is better. However, it is absolutely critical that I can set things up so I only have to pay for VMs when I actually need them rather than keep paying for VMs that aren't in use.

Comment: As this is asking to recommend a tool, this will likely be closed as off topic.  I will say however that Azure will do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: This should probably be migrated over to http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Azure has the capability you are looking for. You can upload your own images and then quickly deploy extra-small machines based on it. On Azure you can turf off the VM's through the Azure portal after you are finished with them and you will not be charged. Make sure that you do it through the portal and not the windows session or you will continue to be billed.

Check out this link for pricing information:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/

You can follow these steps to upload your image to your azure account:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-create-upload-vhd-windows-server/

Also, you can scale up very easy in the azure portal so this might help reduce your need for spinning up multiple machines.

Comment: If you [shut down the VM with Azure powershell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495269.aspx) it will dealocate the VM instance as well and you will not be charged.  Just as it does in the portal.

Comment: You'll pay for storage when a VM is shutdown even if it is deallocated.  If you use a VM image based on 2012 and sparsely format the drives (in Windows Quick Format) then you'll only be charged for in-use bytes in blob storage.